# Shorter jQuery onclick function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a simple draw editor with HTML and jQuery. But I have 100 times the same code for each button:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#1').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("black");
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  color: white;
}

.black {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="1" class="hidden">_</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This work for me, but I have done this 100 times and asking myself how can I do this shorter?

Comment: Um... `<button class="togglething hidden">_</button>` and `$(".togglething").click(...);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with using a class selector instead of button identificators.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hidden").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("black");
  });
});
```

Full code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hidden').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("black");
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  color: white;
}

.black {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="1" class="hidden">_</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="2" class="hidden">_</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another class to each button like this:

```html
<button id="1" class="hidden toggleBtn">_</button>
```

Then your jQuery will be:

```js
$('.toggleBtn').click(function(){  
  $(this).toggleClass("black");  
});
```

And that will make all buttons with that class toggleable.

```js
$('.toggleBtn').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("black");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  color: white;
}

.black {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="1" class="hidden toggleBtn">_</button>
```

Comment: But that hidden class may be used for other things. Would he want all hidden elements clickable?

Comment: Class name is `hidden`, but look how he uses it above (for color). Those should not be either `white` or `black` (because colors may change later).